# "Value does not exist on HTML element" error in angular 6

Tags: angular, types, angular6, element, getelementbyid

In angular 6 I have the following syntax in my template

```
<form [formGroup]="eventEditForm" (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()"  >  
    <div *ngFor='let item of array;let i = index'>                    
       <input id ='myId{{i}}' type="text" value='{{item.name}}' >  
       <button type="button" (click)='edit(item.id,i)' >save</button>                
    </div>     

    <input type="text"  formControlName="eventType"  >                    
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>                    
 </form>
```

This is inside a form but I have not set the textfields of the `ngFor` with a `formControlName` and in my reactive form I do

```
  eventEditForm= this.formBuilder.group({        
    eventType:['']
  });
```

Because the  `array` that produces the whole list of textfields  via `ngFor` is dynamic, I dont have a standard number to declare in the `formBuilder`

So I end up with a list of text fields, all with id like `myId1`, `myId2` etc.

Then in typescript I do

```
 edit(id,i){
   let name = document.getElementById ( 'myld'+i ).value;
   console.log('name  ', name); 
 }
```

This works and I can get the current value of every text field.

I get no errors, but the VisualStudio Code marks the `value` of `let name = document.getElementById ( 'myld'+i ).value;` and the message says `Property value does not exist on type HTMLElement`.

What does this mean and how can I fix it? The code works fine, but I still want to remove that warning.

Thanks

Comment: you're basically ignoring angular in almost every line of code you put here and the only thing that bothers you is TSLINT warning you about type-safety ? i'm tempted to say `// tslint:disable-next-line` but i won't.

Comment: @Stavm It is a fact that irony helped to solve countless problems

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation has few of issues like you are accessing DOM element directly which is not advisable. You can change your implementation as -

### html

```
<div *ngFor='let item of array;let i = index'>                    
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='item.name' >  
   <button type="button" (click)='edit(item)' >save</button>                
</div>
```

### ts

```
edit(item){
   //let name = document.getElementById ( 'myld'+i ).value; //<-- this is not required.
   console.log('name  ', item.name);  //<-- you can use item for editing
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I get an error. The `ngFor` is inside a form tag, but its not part of the form, this is why I originally said that this is not in a form. Check my edited question and you will see. Because of this markup I get the error `ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead. ` Any idea how to fix my code? Thanks again

Comment: if you have `ngForm` then you should use `formControlName` instead of `ngModel` Refer this article for more info - https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular2-building-nested-reactive-forms-7978ecd145e4